# Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, object, default, stdclass

I need to set the object variable at run time, it is working, but PHP returns me:

Creating default object from empty value (/sct/fw FW_List.class.php:1142)

```
function initTemplates(&$object, $tpl_names)
{

 global $FW_LIST_CONFIGURATION;
     $is_custom = array();

     foreach($tpl_names as $tpl_type) {
        $object->$tpl_type =  new template();
        $object->$tpl_type->setTemplateText($FW_LIST_CONFIGURATION["templates"][$tpl_type]);
            // place the defauts template values
        $object->$tpl_type->setPlace( $FW_LIST_CONFIGURATION["css"][$tpl_type]);
  }
  return $is_custom;
}
```

ps. i can't use `$object = new stdClass`, because $object is a pointer.

Comment: 1. PHP doesn't support pointers so how `$object` could be a pointer? 2. Since PHP5 all objects are by default passed by reference, so you should omit `&`. 3. You're using undefined variables `$stdObj` and `$$FW_LIST_CONFIGURATION`.

Comment: sorry, my code looks like this: $object->$tpl_type and 
so I wrote here, I missed the time to ask the question :\

Comment: I edited the question, putting the original function, the way it is in my code.

Comment: the error is this line: $object->$tpl_type =  new template();
help!

Answer (score 1):

resolved, the secret was to use Array;

```
$object->test[$tpl_type] =  new template();
$object->$tpl_type = $object->test[$tpl_type];
$object->$tpl_type->setTemplateText($FW_LIST_CONFIGURATION["templates"][$tpl_type]);
```